# Anonymous UserId is not storing in aspnet_user table in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, anonymous

I create a website and visit it by clicking in a button. so that i become an anonymous user, but when I check aspnetuser table in database, then I not found anonymous id in any table. when anonymous user gets enter into the database.

I turned on anonymous authentication to true in the web.config file. and browse mu website, so that I become an anonymous user, then I checked aspnetuser table but I don't see that users anonymous id there.

Comment: can you able to brief your problem - [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The WHOLE idea and concept of a anonymous user is the security system is 100% by-passed and ignored and not required. So, little surprise that no "user" is in the user table used for authentication, since by adopting a anonymous user, then no authentication bits and parts are EVEN called and used by the authentication system, and hence no "id" is required, nor will be used at all.  If in code you test for no logon, and want to say use somve value of 0 for id, then that's your choice. The security system not going to do anything at all here, and is the whole point of not being logged on.